# Store Data Using Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Developing a chrome extension,I need to store the data in extension,It may include text and

Image please provide the best ways to do this.

1.Is there any way to connect chrome extension with local database?.

Have researched on net only very few details are available,could someone help.

Comment: You can read about `chrome.storage` here http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: Thanks,for me i am planning to port that it to firefox/safari,Is it possible to use my sql here.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by udidu, use chrome.storage. You can store images as [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) or blobs.

Comment: sorry to respond to a really old thread but do you have a good example of storing a blob in chrome.storage?  I attempted it and the value that got stored was "{"type":"image/jpeg","size":42123}".  I'd rather use a blob instead of a base64 url if I can, because it is more compact.